# Segmentation error in Vala

Tags: gtk, glade, vala

Please, tell me what the problem is. After receiving the input field from the Glade file and attempting to use it, a segmentation error is caused.

```
namespace MyApp {
  class MyAppClass : Object {
    Entry myAppEntry;
    public MyAppClass () {
      Builder builder = new Builder.from_file("myApp.ui");
      myAppEntry = builder.get_object("myAppEntry") as Entry;
    }
    public void button_click(){
      stdout.write(myAppEntry.get_text().data); //There is a segmentation error
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Builder.get_object.html get_object () returns null when the object is not found. Most likely `myAppEntry` is null and that's why you get the segfault.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff, get_object возвращает поле ввода, но обратиться к нему можно только внутри функции MyAppClass. В функции button_click происходит ошибка.

Comment: Please write in English. According to auto translation you're wondering why the segfault does occur in the event handler and not the constructor method ... It's the dereferencing of a null pointer (calling `.get_text ()` on it) that is causing a segfault, not assigning null to `myAppEntry`. You can assign null values to variables just fine in Vala (unless experimental-non-null mode is enabled).

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff, I translate with google. And I did not understand your answer a little, if I access myAppEntry inside the MyAppClass function, I get the value, and if out - the segmentation error.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff, okay, 
how do I correctly specify the ID of a field that is deep in the window structure?

Comment: not commenting the code quality. You can check and/assert before calling stdout write method. Example, return_if_fail (myAppEntry != null) before stdout.write. This won't solve the problem though, just avoid the segfault.

Comment: @JoséFonte, I still did not understand what to do with the mistake ..

Comment: If builder.get_object fails to retrieve the widget then it will return null. You cannot invoke methods on null. null it's not an instance of the class. post your glade file so that we can verify the problem

Comment: @JoséFonte, If I access myAppEntry inside the MyAppClass function, there is no error.

Comment: we can't replicate your error, with the given code. Please submit relevant code like the glade file and signal connection.

Comment: Why did not anyone say that before "entry myAppEntry" you need to write "[GtkChield]"?

Comment: You are probably confused with different methods used to load glad files. There is a manual method using get_object () and there is a newer template based method where you decorate your objects with attributes (like [GtkChild]).

Comment: Anyway: As it stands this question is not up to stackoverflow standards. You should post a minimal, complete, verifiable example (MCVE): https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve